# Reload Custom view type on click each time-Odoo8

Tags: javascript, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8

- I have created a new view type like form view and when I create new thing from the form view and switch to my custom view I see no update till I refresh the whole site. I want to know how to reload this custom view to be able to retrieve the data each time I click on my custom view.
- I have created the view on java script and everything work good except reloading the data each time I click the view.
- I found this code and I have called a function in the views.js, I inherit from the core web module

  ```
  var zoser_book = new openerp.Model('zoser.book');      
  zoser_book.call('reload_controller'[view_type]).then(function(reload_ok){
  console.log(reload_ok);
  });
  ```
- then in python I did this:

  ```
  def reload_controller(self, cr, uid, view_type, context = None):
  model_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
  print model_obj
  data_id = model_obj._get_id(cr, uid, 'zoser_book', 'zoser_book_views')
  print data_id
  view_id = model_obj.browse(cr, uid, data_id).res_id
  print view_id
  return {
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
      'name': _('String'),
      'res_model': 'zoser.book',
      'view_type': 'bookview',
      'view_mode': 'bookview',
      'view_id': view_id,
      'target': 'current',
      'nodestroy': True,
  }
  ```
- but I still see no update if I add new book from form view and switch to my custom view no update till I refresh the whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reload any view you have to do all your work inside the record tag on XML to be able to automatic reload as Odoo does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return {
'type': 'ir.actions.client',
'tag': 'reload',
'target':'inline',
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: the question here where can i put your code. i am put a condition on my custom view selection if the user hit the button of the view, so where can i put in java script or python ????and if i will call a function from java script to the python the return object from python what i will make with it in java script,
hope my point reached to you